# Not showing bundled images on first app-start

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

We integrate a ReactNative app within a normal native one. If we load the (offline) bundle, that also contains some images, the following happens:

- **first app start / first RN instance:** 
  no local images are being shown, remote ones do work
- **second (+ sub-sequent) starts:** 
  everything works just fine.

As I've also tried including the picture using a base64 encoded string, i dont think its related to the actual bundle itself.

Well, as i couldnt find anything specific about this bug, i thought about asking on here, if anybody knows something on how to fix that?

---

**Note:** happens on both platforms (Android, iOS)

**Note 2:** happened on RN 0.36, RN 0.50 and 0.51, cant try it out on RN 0.54 as of now :-/

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me,

```
<Image
     onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}
      style={styles.styleName}
      resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
      source={require('./sample_7.png')} />
```